# How to read 2D int array from binary file in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I have a 2D integer array to store x,y coordinates. I checked out a few functions to write 2D array into a file but cannot find anything that is able to read that binary file on load and push it into a new 2 dimensional integer array.

This is my world generator function which saves it to the file:

```
public WorldGenerator()
{
    int worldSizeX = 100;
    int worldSizeY = 100;
    int[,] world = new int[worldSizeX*worldSizeY, 2];

    Logger.log("Generating world...");

    for(int x = 0; x < worldSizeX; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            System.Random random = new System.Random();
            int itemID = random.Next(0, 1);

            world[x, y] = itemID;
        }
    }

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/ConsoleGame/world/default.wd", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

    for (int x = 0; x < worldSizeX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        {
            bw.Write(world[x, y]);
        }
    }

    bw.Close();
    fs.Close();
    Logger.log("World generated.");
}
```

Any good idea that could work for reading this file in? I should get back a 2D integer array and `world[0,0]` should get me the itemid. I am new to c# and this would be just a basic console application.
I have also seen others answering similar questions but none of them are worked for me yet. Maybe because this save function is wrong or something else.

**EDIT:**

Here is how I load the file:

```
using (var filestream = File.Open(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/ConsoleGame/world/default.wd", FileMode.Open))
using (var binaryStream = new BinaryReader(filestream))
{
    while (binaryStream.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(binaryStream.ReadInt32());
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++)` be `for(int y = 0; y < worldSizeY ; y++)`?

Comment: @Michael No the array is `new int[worldSizeX*worldSizeY, 2]`  so it's actually the first for loop that's wrong.

Comment: Oh because it creates 10000 and only populates 100 of them if i am right?

Comment: If you are pushing binary data with non fixed length you have to put the size of the data before you save the data, otherwise, you will not be able to read the data.

Comment: I edited my question and it prints out a lot of 0's. I just realised that `random.Next(0, 1);` is first include second exclude. So it will never give out 1 when there is only 1 choice it has which is 0.

Answer (score 0):

need Newtonsoft.Json

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int worldSizeX = 100;
            int worldSizeY = 100;

            int[,] world = new int[worldSizeX * worldSizeY, 2];

            System.Random random = new System.Random();

            for (int x = 0; x < worldSizeX; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
                {

                    int itemID = random.Next(0, 2);
                    world[x, y] = itemID;
                }
            }


            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(world, Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("WriteText.txt", json);

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("WriteText.txt");
            int[,] deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[,]>(text);

            //use "deserialized"

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: That will produce a _text file_. Numbers will be stored as their decimal string representations.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called "Serialization".
Start with the simple builtin [binary serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization).

[Serializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute does the magic here.

By the moment you'll realize it is not the best option, you'll be able to use something more suiting your needs, like [proto-buf](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net).

I've also changed ints to shorts in your example. I doubt you need 32 bits for each world cell, so we can save a bit of hard drive space.

```
[Serializable]
public class WorldState
{
    public short[,] Items { get; set; }

    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        if (filename == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filename));

        using (var file = File.Create(filename))
        {
            var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            serializer.Serialize(file, this);
        }
    }

    public static WorldState Load(string filename)
    {
        if (filename == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filename));
        if (!File.Exists(filename)) throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", filename);

        using (var file = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            return serializer.Deserialize(file) as WorldState;
        }
    }
}

public class WorldStateTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanSaveAndLoad()
    {
        var ws = new WorldState
        {
            Items = new short[,]
            {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
            }
        };
        // save the world state to file. Find it and see what's inside 
        ws.Save("./ws.bin");

        // load the world back
        var loaded = WorldState.Load("./ws.bin");

        // check a new world state got loaded
        Assert.NotNull(loaded);
        // and it still has items
        Assert.NotEmpty(loaded.Items);
        // and the items are the same as we saved
        Assert.Equal(ws.Items, loaded.Items);
    }
}
```